# How to add a condition in a WHERE statement based on a JOIN

Tags: oracle

In my WHERE condition, the following 
w.physical_country = y.destination_country_code

works fine except when there is the country United Kingdom. This is because in w.physical_country column the value is 'UK' whereas in y.destination_country_code the value is 'GB'

Hence the where condition will skip this condition as they don't match, whoever in reality they do match and should be added to the table. How would you add a condition to take this into account ?

```
dest_leg AS(
SELECT y.* 
FROM 
       (
       SELECT
             y.shipment_id,
             y.route_id,
             min(leg_sequence_id) max_leg_sequence_id
       FROM 
             posimorders.sc_execution_eu.o_detailed_routes_v2 y
             LEFT JOIN warehouse_attributes w                  -- Joining to add country of dest SC
             ON w.warehouse_id = y.leg_warehouse_id

       where 1=1

             and w.physical_country = y.destination_country_code

       group by
             1,2
       ) x
       INNER JOIN posimorders.sc_execution_eu.o_detailed_routes_v2 y
       on x.route_id = y.route_id and x.shipment_id = y.shipment_id and y.leg_sequence_id = x.max_leg_sequence_id
),
```

Comment: `(w.physical_country = y.destination_country_code OR (w.physical_country IN ('UK','GB') AND y.destination_country_code IN ('UK','GB'))`

Comment: = decode(y.destination_country_code,'GB','UK',y.destination_country_code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the UK vs GB you can use:

```
if(w.physical_country='UK','GB',w.physical_country) = y.destination_country_code
```

Comment: not sure why but it says syntax error near if. Im using oracle

Comment: OK. Was answering the question at the time the question had the mysql-tag. In Oracle you can use the CASE WHEN-clause.